# Joining and cutting mpeg 2 video files

Tags: .net, windows, video, ffmpeg

I have multiple mpeg2 video files. What I need to do is get a clip of video that is contained in several of these mpeg2 videos. What I'm doing at the moment is:

- Join them using the command:

  ```
      copy /b file1.mpg + ... + fileN.mpg output.mpg
  ```
- The ouput.mpg duration is wrong so I'm using FFMpeg to fix that:

  ```
      ffmpeg -y -i output.mpeg -target pal-dvd outputFixed.mpg
  ```

The problem is when I try to extract only one portion of this output.mpg, at the same time I "fix" it, with the -ss and -t FFMpeg commands becouse the video duration is wrong as i said.

So the question is:

- Is there any way to combine Mpeg2 files without getting the duration wrong?
- Is there any way to fix the duration of a Mpeg2 file and extract one portion at the same time?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You should use -vcodec copy -acodec copy so you don't waste time decoding and encoding the audio and video streams (not to mention degrading quality)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [ffmpeg FAQ](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-can-I-join-video-files_003f):

> 3.13 How can I join video files?
>
> A few multimedia containers (MPEG-1, MPEG-2 PS, DV) allow to join
>   video files by merely concatenating them.
>
> Hence you may concatenate your multimedia files by first transcoding
>   them to these privileged formats, then using the humble cat command
>   (or the equally humble copy under Windows), and finally transcoding
>   back to your format of choice.
>
> ffmpeg -i input1.avi -same_quant intermediate1.mpg ffmpeg -i
>   input2.avi -same_quant intermediate2.mpg cat intermediate1.mpg
>   intermediate2.mpg > intermediate_all.mpg ffmpeg -i
>   intermediate_all.mpg -same_quant output.avi Notice that you should
>   either use -same_quant or set a reasonably high bitrate for your
>   intermediate and output files, if you want to preserve video quality.
>
> Also notice that you may avoid the huge intermediate files by taking
>   advantage of named pipes, should your platform support it:
>
> mkfifo intermediate1.mpg mkfifo intermediate2.mpg ffmpeg -i
>   input1.avi -same_quant -y intermediate1.mpg < /dev/null & ffmpeg -i
>   input2.avi -same_quant -y intermediate2.mpg < /dev/null & cat
>   intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg |\ ffmpeg -f mpeg -i - -same_quant
>   -c:v mpeg4 -acodec libmp3lame output.avi Similarly, the yuv4mpegpipe format, and the raw video, raw audio codecs also allow concatenation,
>   and the transcoding step is almost lossless. When using multiple
>   yuv4mpegpipe(s), the first line needs to be discarded from all but the
>   first stream. This can be accomplished by piping through tail as seen
>   below. Note that when piping through tail you must use command
>   grouping, { ;}, to background properly.
>
> For example, let’s say we want to join two FLV files into an
>   output.flv file:
>
> mkfifo temp1.a mkfifo temp1.v mkfifo temp2.a mkfifo temp2.v mkfifo
>   all.a mkfifo all.v ffmpeg -i input1.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le
>   -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp1.a < /dev/null & ffmpeg -i input2.flv -vn -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 - > temp2.a < /dev/null &
>   ffmpeg -i input1.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - > temp1.v < /dev/null & {
>   ffmpeg -i input2.flv -an -f yuv4mpegpipe - < /dev/null | tail -n +2 >
>   temp2.v ; } & cat temp1.a temp2.a > all.a & cat temp1.v temp2.v >
>   all.v & ffmpeg -f u16le -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i all.a \
>          -f yuv4mpegpipe -i all.v \
>          -same_quant -y output.flv rm temp[12].[av] all.[av]

Comment: I had read that: "or the equally humble copy under Windows" very humble but not very useful in this case, you can reproduce the file but the duration is wrong, i think it got something to do with the file header, it only keeps the first one.

Comment: Yes, that's why you transcode it with ffmpeg again after you concatenate the files.

Comment: ok so the idea is: Copy(command) -> Transcode(FFMpeg) -> Extract(FFMpeg). It's going to take too long!

Comment: Yep much better now. -vcodec copy (no audio ) speed up the process dramatically. Great piece of code FFMpeg. Thanks!